# I want dynamic get height of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, height

I create a TableView by this code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        {
            return 1;
        }
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {
            return 100;
        }
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *cellString = @"cellString";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellString];
            if(cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellString];
                NSLog(@"count : %d",count++);
    }
            return cell;
        }
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            return cell.frame.size.height;
        }
```

i find this TableView doesn't reused, but i want dynamic get height of TableViewCell, i'm very bothered me.I want help,Thanks!

Comment: why are u calling [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; method

Comment: have any method to dynamic get height of TableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to get height of tableviewcell. Because you can direct return your height for particular cell like that...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ------------- add your more stuff here ---------------
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
      return yourHeight;
}
```

Comment: But now I don't know its height

Comment: If you don't know in that case you need to calculate dynamic.